How to make accessible readonly checkboxes/radios that can't be modified?
I'm in the process of making reusable input components for a variety of input types, and I'm trying to figure out the recommended way to go about an accessible readonly input - that shouldn't be able to be modified.
For example, if there's a form that's only submitted once, and a user wants to go back and look at what they filled out.
How should its inputs be rendered?

The readonly property isn't valid for checkboxes and radios (same goes for aria-readonly), so while it works for the text based inputs, I need an alternative for checkboxes and radios.

An input with the disabled property is removed from the tabbing order, and it's been pointed out that disabled conveys that the input isn't relevant - which is not the intent.
<label>
  <input type="checkbox" disabled />
  A checkbox
</label>


Another solution I tried was to just not use inputs at all when not in edit mode. This is easy enough for a text input, but for a lot of other input types this seemed not ideal.
Ensuring that the original action is still understandable for a screen reader would be a new challenge - e.g for what was a radio group input, I'd want to make sure I properly convey "This option was between these radio options, and this one was picked".
This doesn't seem like an great solution - to manually try and convey the same information the input would give.

One could use aria-disabled="true", and manually prevent change of the input. But this has the same issue as just disabled - that it doesn't convey the right state "relevant, but uneditable".
<label>
  <input id="my-checkbox" type="checkbox" aria-disabled="true" />
  A checkbox
</label>

document.getElementById("my-checkbox")?.addEventListener("click", event => {
  event.preventDefault();
})


I suggest you should not use input fields to render read-only values. Reading values inside a text field is not nearly as easy as reading plain text. Definitely shouldn't use disabled, disabled means it's not active and not relevant. If you really want to show what other options were available, then my suggestion doesn't apply but I would still provide a different way to show that information. Lastly, using readonly does get announced by VoiceOver, I'm not sure why your screen reader is not announcing it.

@RuanMendes agreed for the text input! But as said that solution doesn't translate well to other types of input. E.g. for a radio group - even in read mode, you'd still want to have the context of which options are/were available.
If readonly is announced and my VoiceOver is just acting up, then using the readonly attribute (with JavaScript to manually prevent the input from changing) might to be a better alternative than aria-disabled.

readonly is not a valid attribute for input in general, only for specific input types. Checkbox isn't one of them. That might explain the screenreader behaviour.
I've used the disable-by-script before, but in most cases there might not be any useful need to still show the checkbox at all. As a user, I usually don't care much about options I can't choose :)

@René ooh, okay, I wasn't aware readonly was limited like that, thank you! :) And in some contexts I agree it's best to just not show it at all and my setting page example was maybe a bad one, as that could just always be in edit mode. But for other cases, when something is only submitted once for example - it's sometimes important to be able to go back and look at what's been submitted.

Does this answer your question? When I should use readonly instead of disabled

@Sean not really no, I'm looking for what's the accessible way to have an input be non-editable while keeping it in the normal tabbing flow order and to announce it in a way that makes sense for a screen reader - that this information is relevant to read right now, it's just not editable. The linked question does not answer this except mention readonly, which as previous comments point out - isn't an option for all input types, even if I did manually prevent a change.

My primary examples include checkboxes and radio groups specifically because these are the ones I'm struggling the most to find a solution for.

@Norah Things don't have to be in the tabbing flow to be read by the screen reader. I suggest you ask ChatGPT the following: "When displaying an HTML form in read-only mode. Should I use input fields set to readonly? Or would I be better off just rendering the form values without form inputs, just text?" It gave me reasonable feedback. The problem with your question is that there is no right answer and SO is for questions that have a definitive answer. Therefore, I'm voting to close it as opinion based.

In Help users to Check answers, the GOV.UK design system suggest a dl description list with the answers given in the <dd> element, as you suggested. No controls need to be there. It allows for a nicely streamlined view of the answers, and doesn’t involve of the clutter of control logic, that a screen reader user would need to listen to.

Won't save this as the final answer, as there might still be better solutions and there seems to be some general discussions ongoing about the intent of a disabled state.
However, for now - I've ended up going with the solution to manually prevent edit with aria-disabled.
The reason being that there is no concept of readonly for checkboxes and radios (even aria-readonly has spotty support), and the usual solution people would arrive at is to disable the input, so I figure keeping it in the tabbing order by using aria-disabled instead of disabled - is an okay compromise.
Some GitHub issues around the topic I found helpful in my decision:

Why is aria-readonly allowed for checkboxes and radios?
Provide a way to have disabled form controls to be submitted (was:
readonly attribute)

